# Defining atom? in clojure

Tags: clojure

Common Lisp has an `atom` predicate, but Clojure doesn't seem to have an equivalent - atom in Clojure is a completely different thing.

In ANSI Common Lisp, Paul Graham defines it as `(not (consp x))`.

Would `(not (coll? x))` be the correct implementation?

I'm not very used to the collection abstraction yet.

**Edit:**

I'd need this predicate for a function to copy a tree, for example:

```
(defn our-copy-tree
  [tr]
  (if-not (coll? tr)
    tr
    (cons (our-copy-tree (first tr))
          (our-copy-tree (rest tr)))))
```

Is this right?

Comment: depends on how would you like to treat java arrays and collections: they are not colls, so `(not (coll? (int-array 1)))` would return true.

Comment: if you would like to treat them as colls , not atoms, check this function from old contrib: https://github.com/clojure/clojure-contrib/blob/b8d2743d3a89e13fc9deb2844ca2167b34aaa9b6/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/core.clj#L78 this complexity, is the consequence of clojure's "sequability" thing: almost all the functions working with collections make seqs from `Iterable`, `java.util.Collection`, or java arrays, so I wouldn't treat them as atoms in clojure terms..

Comment: oh, forgot about strings! do you treat them as atoms or collections? In fact the whole `atom` thing is much more fuzzy in clojure, then in common lisp, because clojure chooses the way of sequences unification, while in common lisp only cons cell is not an atom.

Comment: What `atom` means in common lisp and what `atom` means in Clojure are not the same. What do you intend to mean here? It might make sense to describe the CL meaning explicitly in the question [if that's what you want], so folks coming from a Clojure background aren't confused.

Comment: (see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665132/what-is-the-difference-between-an-atom-in-common-lisp-and-an-atom-in-clojure)

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, so it turns out `coll?` would not be the Clojure equivalent to Common Lisp `consp`.

The reason is that the empty list `()` is a `coll`, so I was getting a stack overflow - while with CL `(consp '()); => false)`.

The right answer is also to check if the tr is empty, thusly:

```
(defn our-copy-tree
  [tr]
  (if (or (not (coll? tr)) (empty? tr))
    tr
    (cons (our-copy-tree (first tr))
          (our-copy-tree (rest tr)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

In general Clojure doesn't depend fundamentally on cons cells and atoms as other Lisps do. In fact you often end up using vectors and maps far more than actual lists in Clojure (if you leave out the act of actually writing Clojure code). That's why the word "atom" is used to refer to an STM concept in Clojure. The traditional Lisp concept just isn't as useful.

So you taking the negation of `coll?` is a reasonable approximation of a Lisp atom, but Lisp atoms are generally a foreign concept in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

First the quick answer:

```
(def atomic? (complement coll?))
(map atomic? [0 "hi" [] {}]) => (true true false false)
```

But as @leetwinksi and @efraimmgon observed, the answer depends on what you consider an atom.  For example, one could also define an atom as not-`seqable?` (i.e. `(complement seqable?)`), which would further restrict what was considered atomic, since many types including strings can be treated as sequences.

Comment: `(atomic? (int-array 1))` => true , `(atomic? (java.util.ArrayList.))` => true

Comment: because `(map coll? [(java.util.ArrayList.) (int-array 1)])`  => `(false false)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that edge-case.  But am I right in thinking that it's still a reasonable definition, because it mirrors the functionality of the built-in `coll?`.

Comment: i know that, that's the reason i wrote a comment: they are not `coll?` but still they are sequable. So are they atoms or not?

Comment: depends on what you consider to be an atom. For example `map` treats java arrays (and strings and a bunch of other stuff) as collections (as lots of other clojure functions do). Is it atom then? or collection?

Comment: As a noob, I would intuitively want to say that they should be collections.  But I am a clojurian because I respect the thought that went into the language design, so I would be curious to know if `colll?` is implemented this way by design due to a tradeoff, or by accident due to backwards-compatibility.

Comment: Well, `coll?` was for sure planned to query clojure's native collections, so it's only logical.. But there is a concept of "sequable" thing, which can be converted to clojure's sequence with `seq` function. Unfortunately `seq` throws an exception, if you pass anything not sequable to it, otherwise it could have been a nice point for checking. You could probably go with `try/catch` probing, but it is too ugly and unneeded. The answer to op's question is: "you have to decide, what "atom" means, because clojure is not common lisp or scheme".

Comment: I updated my answer to recommend using `seq?` instead of `coll?`.  I mentally kicked myself for not realizing that it was that simple sooner; thanks for pushing the issue!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114921/discussion-between-adam-lee-and-leetwinski).

Comment: I guess `seqable?` fits better than `seq?` -> `(seq? {}) ; => false` while `(seqable? {}); => true`.

Comment: You're correct @efraimmgon, I looked into it and gave updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`atom`s in Clojure are completely different as you noted.
At first I checked the class instance:

```
(defn atom? [x] (instance? clojure.lang.Atom x))
```

However that may be relying on implementation details.
Instead, I now use the Clojure interface:

```
(defn atom? [x] (instance? clojure.lang.IAtom x))
```

Note, there is a corresponding protocol in cljs: `cljs.core/IAtom`

Comment: This is answering according to the Clojure meaning of `atom`, vs the CL meaning; I gather the question to be asking the other. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665132/what-is-the-difference-between-an-atom-in-common-lisp-and-an-atom-in-clojure

Comment: I found this page because I wanted a predicate that would identify *Clojure* atoms, so although this answer doesn't answer OP's (somewhat confusingly worded) question, it answers mine.  It works, but it's Clojure-specific; in Clojurescript `(defn atom? [x] (instance? cljs.core/Atom x))` seems to work.